# Is there another way to say "needn't have done"?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect

I'm learning modal verbs now and get in trouble with "need" one.

In my textbook it is said that:

> don't need to == needn't -- present simple
>   didn't need to -- past simple
>   needn't have done -- present perfect

In some inexplicable reason I think that *needn't have done* sounds weird (may be because I haven't ever heard of such construction).

So my question is: Is there a sentence that equal to *needn't have done* but without the *needn't* part (like the past simple one)? Or everything is just fine with it and I shouldn't keep in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, all of the examples are a little weird. *Need* is very rarely used as a modal any more, and it's likely that you'll be able to go your entire life without ever encountering it in speech. It is sufficient that you be able to recognize and understand sentences like the above, but don't expect to use them much. Just treat *need* like any other verb:

> Present: `don't need to`
>
> Present perfect: `haven't needed to`
>
> Simple past: `didn't need to`
>
> Past perfect: `hadn't needed to`

That said, the three examples are grammatically correct, strictly speaking. The phrase *needn't have done* is a fine, though archaic, way of saying *didn't need to have done...*

Answer (score 4):

When you write *I don't need to*, or *I didn't need to*, you are not using *need* as modal verb; you are using it as a normal verb.

Modal verbs are different from the normal verbs because:

1. The verb doesn't take the *-s* for the third person.
2. To negate a modal verb, you add *not* after the modal verb, even in the present and past tense.
3. Many modal verbs cannot be used in the past tenses or the future tenses.

> She can speak English correctly.
>   She should not be here, now.
>   <strike>She will can go with us.</strike>
>   <strike>She musted study very hard.</strike>

Using *need* as modal verb (*need* is used as modal verb only in negatives, or questions), you should write:

> I need not [verb].
>   I need not have [past participle of the verb].

When *need* is used as modal verb, it is used to express necessity or obligation.

> Need I say more?
>   I need not have worried.

When *need* is not used as modal verb (which happens most of the times), then it is used as in the following sentences:

> I need to go, now.
>   I didn't need to know all the details.
>   I have not needed that for ages.

Comment: Well, `need` in positives is always a normal verb, correct?

Comment: _Need_ in positives is always a normal verb. It is probable you will find _need_ used as modal verb in very few cases.

Comment: "need" used modally really gives a nice impression of precision and slight sophistication. Needn't you know how to use it properly? :)

Comment: @wazoox: I do need ;-)

Comment: also thanks for question fixes, it is amazing that I did not make mistakes, except of decoration ones ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of *needn't have done* is *should have done*

For example:

> It's too late to call the bank. I *should have done* that earlier.

Which is opposite in sentiment to

> I bought oranges yesterday! I *needn't have done* that today.

Which can be equally expressed as

> I bought oranges yesterday! I *didn't need to do* that today.

Comment: +1 Wow, didn't expect to see  that aspect of *needn't* raised here. Was losing the will to die reading so many answers without seeing it ...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with "needn't have done". It means, simply, "did not need to do [something]." This is true even though the cases are different. The actions that have been accomplished were done in the past in both cases.

> You paid my bill? You needn't have done that. I was fully prepared to pay it myself.
>
> You paid my bill? You did not need to do that. I was fully prepared to pay it myself.

Comment: Yes, I can get the difference, I just wanted to get the some sentence to replace it with something more modern, like @JSBangs gave here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12342/neednt-do-and-neednt-have-done/12344#12344

Comment: @zerkms: Then I sugges you show @JSBangs a little love by accepting his answer, or at least up-voting it.

Comment: I know how SE works (I'm 16k+ SO user) ;-) Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like you to send the exammple of needn't to my e-mail for example:

1- Iam  a student in a school . I'm very tired so I needn't work so hard .
2- He is a journalist . he is in his office. He can't write any report because he needs more truth information.
3- Jane is a secreatary .she can't answer the phone because her phone is out of order so she  needs a telepnohe reepairer.
             etc...

Comment: The phrase looks strange at least "I'm very tired so I needn't work so hard". You're tired. So what? I'm also very tired but I need to work hard because I'm not rich.