# "Didn't need to" vs "Needn't have done"

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

Page 315 of the Collins English Usage reads

> If you are talking about the past and you want to say that it was not
> necessary for someone to do something on a particular occasion, you
> say that they **didn't need/have to**.
>
> *I didn't need to say anything at all. Fortunately, she didn't have to
> choose.*
>
> However, in a reporting clause you can use *needn't*.
>
> *They knew they needn't bother about me.*
>
> If someone has done something and you want to say that it was not
> necessary, you can say that they **needn't have done** it.
>
> *I was wondering whether you were getting properly fed and looked
> after, but I needn't have worried, need I?*

However, I cannot see any difference of meaning/usage between *Didn't need to* vs *Needn't have done*

Comment: I didn't have/need to worry and I needn't have worried carry the same semantics. However, not everyone is familiar with needn't have, especially AmE speakers.

Comment: “ I didn't need to soy anything at oil.” Seriously? On p. 315 of Collins English Usage? Does that exist? How about a link?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s copied from another forum and includes as an example “I didn't need to soy anything at oil.“ Thus troll.

Comment: @Xanne - Soy/oil  might just be an OCR error.

Comment: @Lambie: Seriously??? Americans are perfectly capable of understanding *needn't have*, and even use it occasionally. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=needn%27t+have%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cneedn%27t+have%3Aeng_gb_2019+&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneed%20not%20have%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20not%20have%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor I never said Americans don't understand it or use it. But I do say it is not exactly heard down at your local convenience store where, thank God, Google has not yet poked its ugly nose in. But you needn't believe me, need you? The Brits use is much more frequently, and often without a tag at the end.

Comment: @Lambie what do you mean by "a tag at the end"?

Comment: Tags are all those little auxiliary verbs at the end of spoken utterances or sentences. Often, non-natives have a terrible time with them. For example: I don't approve of hunting, do you? They hated that trip, didn't they? I'd go, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Lambie why is that related to _needn't have_?

Comment: So, with "needn't have done something", one would not usually use a tag. However, with They didn't need to do it, did they? Or: They didn't have to do it, did they? tags are used. But you needn't worry about all this. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there another way to say "needn't have done"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12342/is-there-another-way-to-say-neednt-have-done)