# Do you say needn't have in AmE?

Tags: american-english, modal-verbs

My textbook says that you can use this construction "needn't have" if you want to say that something that you have done in the past wasn't necessary and you didn't know it was unnecessary, but you have already done that.

For example:

> "You needn't have bought any eggs, we already have a lot in the fridge"

So I'm curious do you say that in American English? Or is there a way to say it in American English?

Comment: You don’t need to buy....You don’t have to buy ..

Comment: Oh yes, there was a mistake in my example, I've corrected it.

Comment: For Americans, that's a very high register, as in super formal and not normal talk.

Comment: Note that what Americans would actually **say** is something like /yu'niɾṇəˌbɔ'ɾɛgz/ 'you needna bought eggs'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there another way to say "needn't have done"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12342/is-there-another-way-to-say-neednt-have-done)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Need* (like *must*) as uncommon as an modal verb in spoken English, and even in writing it is "[rather formal](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/need_3)" (OALD). *Needn't*, common in BrE, is [rare in AmE](https://www.britishcouncilfoundation.id/en/english/articles/british-and-american-english).

To express the absence of a responsibility or obligation, an AmE speaker might still use *need*, but in its transitive form with a *to*-infinitive, or as a noun:

> You didn't need to buy any eggs.

> There was no need to buy any eggs.